# When iterating over a 2D structure, is it faster to iterate over the total length or use nested loops to iterate over the rows and columns?

Tags: c++, for-loop, optimization

I can think of two different ways to iterate over a 2d range, either using nested loops to iterate over the rows and columns separately:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    int x = i % width;
    int y = i / width;
    //Do stuff
}
```

or using a single for loop to iterate over the area and computing the row and column:

```cpp
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

In my application width and height can be *very* large, so I need to know which one will perform better for large numbers of iterations.

Comment: I think there's really no instance in which the difference between the two would be meaningful.

Comment: If you're really keen on optimizing this though I would suggest starting with taking the integer definitions out of the loops. No need to repeat the memory allocations.

Comment: This can be important if your data is `vector<int>` vs `vector<vector<int>>` for example since the memory is not contiguous from one inner vector to another, so you suffer more cache misses. But if your data is otherwise contiguous then the methods are equivalent.

Comment: Until you profile and have measurements and identified bottleneck code, there is no good reason to put in effort to micro-optimize this kind of code.  If profiling shows this part of the code to be a performance concern, only then should it be refactored into more efficient but probably less maintainable and non-obvious code — comment heavily, and keep around a non-micro-optimized reference implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`width * height` might overflow. Signed integer overflow is (still) undefined behavior. `i % 0` is undefined behavior. `i / 0` is undefined behavior too. You can protect the first version against such problems, though in the second version none of this issues is present.

Don't do premature optimization. This:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Is simpler and more readable than the flat loop, and on top of that it is correct (irrespective of the values of `height` and `width`).

If you do care about performance, you should first write correct and tested code and then measure and profile it.